# Generate Crystal Report in C# from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

Another query for employee payroll..

This time I would like to generate the employee payslip for every employee in Crystal Reports by fetching information from a SQL Server database in desires format given below

[image]

and the thing I want to know is how to design the Crystal Report as in given image and get the dynamic details for each employee and generate employee payslips in Crystal Report

Comment: This Link is useful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12694/Creating-Crystal-Reports-using-C-with-Datasets

Comment: the link was something i already know..what i really need is to design the report for multiple employee not in table style format..but in the one as given in image

Comment: i think your problem in Allowances and Deductions list , you can do by design sub report for Allowances and deductions and call it in your main report.

Comment: And you have to group by the employee column in the report design to display each employee separately.

Comment: @Mohammadabumazen your suggestion of sub report was also appreciable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the thing where was i stucking is i m not getting the concept of header and details in crystal report but now i cleared it on my own..i desgined the above report by just dragging all fields in details section of crystal report and then arranging them as needed..

Comment: Can you share your solution, I need it too

Comment: Hi buddy, i have worked on .net tech in my internship project only, 3 yrs back, unfortunately i dont remember what exactly i have done in that project since i have switched to java. Sorry cant help you now.